# How to map a person across a 3 table join (each table is a year)

Tags: sql, join, sql-server-2014

So I apologize in advance if this has been asked before...

1. I have 3 tables, each has the dimensions of People X Attributes (LxW). The attributes include things like *acc_balance*, *withdrawals*, *contributions*, *birth_year*, etc.
2. Each table is a year (2016, 17, 18).
3. The goal is to link individuals via Person_ID across the years with columns *Person_ID*, *Account_ID* and *Transactions* for each year in the final table, similar to below:

[image]

Since the person will have the same ID throughout, it would be cleaner to just have "person".

Things to consider:

1. One person may have several accounts (want to group by *Person_ID*)
2. Want to have *Person* = (*personal_id2018* = *personal_id2017* = *personal_id2016*)

What I've tried:

```
select person = personal_id, 
       Accounts18 = count(a.Account_ID), 
       Accounts17 = count(b.Account_ID), 
       Accounts16 = count(c.Account_ID), 
       Transac18 = a.Transactions, 
       Transac17 = b.Transactions, 
       Transac16 = c.Transactions
from
    (select personal_id, account_id, transactions from dbo.bank2018 group by personal_id) a
inner join
    (select personal_id, account_id, transactions from dbo.bank2017 group by personal_id) b
on a.personal_id = b.personal_id
inner join
    (select personal_id, account_id, transactions from dbo.bank2016 group by personal_id) c
on b.personal_id = c.personal_id
group by person???
```

Thank you everyone!

Comment: I am unclear on what is going into the columns.  Are these identifiers for accounts and transactions?  Are these counts?  Your subqueries are also syntactically incorrect because the `select` directly references columns not in the `group by`.  What do the results look like for a person with multiple accounts and transactions in one year?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want counts in each column.  If so, all the work is done in the subqueries:

```
select b2018.personal_id, b2018.num_accounts_2018, b2018.num_transactions_2018,
       b2017.num_accounts_2017, b2017.num_transactions_2017,
       b2016.num_accounts_2016, b2016.num_transactions_2016
from (select personal_id,
             count(distinct account_id) as num_accounts_2018,
             count(*) as num_transactions_2018
       from dbo.bank2018
       group by personal_id
      ) b2018 inner join
      (select personal_id,
             count(distinct account_id) as num_accounts_2017,
             count(*) as num_transactions_2017
       from dbo.bank2017
       group by personal_id
      ) b2017
      on b2017.personal_id = b2018.personal_id inner join
      (select personal_id,
             count(distinct account_id) as num_accounts_2016,
             count(*) as num_transactions_2016
       from dbo.bank2016
       group by personal_id
      ) b2016
      on b2016.personal_id = b2017.personal_id;
```

Note that this only returns persons who have data in all three tables.  If you want customers who are missing from one or more of the tables, you would want outer joins of some sort.